# How to make top run in background ? It needs to run and log the output. Not die or zombie up

Tags: linux, bash, shell, qnx, qnx-neutrino

I am trying to make a script to log the top output to a file in the background for my embedded system. But as soon as I put it in background, it either exits or zombies up. What is the systems problem with running things in background ?
My script

```
TOP_LOG_FILE=top_log.txt
if [ -e $TOP_LOG_FILE ] ; then
        rm $TOP_LOG_FILE
fi
while true
do
        echo "##"`date`"##" >> $TOP_LOG_FILE
        nohup top -n 1 >> $TOP_LOG_FILE 
        sleep 1
        echo "##xxxxxxxxxxx##" >> $TOP_LOG_FILE
done
```

I am trying to execute it as

```
# nohup sh top_log.sh &


[4] 3051559

appending output to nohup.out

# 


[4] + Stopped (tty output) nohup sh top_log.sh
```

and as

```
[5] 3121193

sh: top_log.sh: cannot execute - No such file or directory

[6] 3121194

# 


[6]   Done                 > /dev/null 

[5]   Done (126)           top_log.sh 

#
```

How do I actually get around this behavior?

Comment: Have you tried the -b option?

Comment: Its on QNX, I only have the follwoing options:
top [-i number] [-d] [-n node] [-p priority]
i = number of iterations
d = dumb terminal output
-n remote node to run on 
-p process priority

Comment: I guess its the equivalent of using -n and -b options only.

Comment: If platform is QNX, why the Linux tag?

Comment: Its supposed to be posix compatible. Thats why. In addition, I do see similar behavior on my ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried the  `-d` option then? Anyway the `linux` tag is not useful because in Ubuntu you can just use `-b`.

Comment: true. I suppose the -b takes care of it in linux.

Comment: The -d uses terminal friendly string formatting. Thats all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
top -n 1 -b
```

Tail that in a loop and append to file.
Wrap your loop in a script and launch it from terminal with &.